# I want to know whether the following is periodic or not periodic

Tags: signal-processing

I have a question about system properties of the following function whether it is periodic or aperiodic.

With an insight, I'd determine the function is aperiodic since the unit-step term looks implying that jump discontinuities occur at odd number times but don't have a detailed solution in mathematical terms.

Many thanks in advance for your help.

$$f(t)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-(2t-n)}u(2t-n)$$

Comment: Did you try to simplify $f(t+\frac{1}{2})$?

Comment: Yes, I also saw the problem in that way at first but was doubtful if there were errors, especially regarding u(t). Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is periodic with period $1/2$ since you have
$$
f(t+1/2)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{-(2t-n+1)}u(2t-n+1)=f(t),
$$
as you can easily see by an index shift in the sum.

Hope this helps...

Comment: First of all, thank you Chris for your quick answer. But can you assure me if jump discontinuities don't take place despite the equation u(t)=u(2t)?

Comment: You're welcome. You can have as many discontinuities as you want. Just define $u$ to be $0$ outside the interval $I=[0,1/2]$ and discontinuous inside. Then you will find that $f(t)=e^{-2t+1}u(2t+1)$ for $t\in I$. If $u$ was discontinuous, then $f$ is also.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $a\gt0$. Every function $f$ defined as $$f(t)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty g(at-n),$$ is periodic with period $____$.

Comment: ?? "Next time", you will choose the answer which suits you best, no?